# Using a checkbox outside of a datagrid to affect its contents

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, datagrid, checkbox

I am using a Checkbox outside of a datagrid. When i select the check box autopostback is true, and this would then show the image, but i cant access the images within the datagrid with that script. If i use a seperate image outside of the datagrid the script works. How can i get this script to work finding when the checkbox out side of the datagrid is checked to then show the image within the datagrid?

The script i am using is

```
<script runat="server">

    Sub Check(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
        If checkShowImages.Checked Then
                img.Visible = True

        Else
            img.Visible = False
        End If
    End Sub

</script>
```

Comment: What is the type of img control??

Comment: if checkbos is checked then the img will be visible else not, right??

Comment: Yes thats right, then images are within a datagrid though and the checkbox is not

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(Assuming your `checkbox`'s id is "CheckBox1" & `DataGrid`'s Id is "Datagrid1")...

```
Sub Check(sender As Object, e As EventArgs)
    For Each r As DataGridItem In Datagrid1.Items
        Try
            r.FindControl("img").Visible = CheckBox1.Checked
        Catch ex As Exception

        End Try
    Next
end sub
```

Hope this helps. Good luck.

Comment: I cannot put Gridview1.Rows  with the error saying Rows is not a member of DataGrid

Comment: No, apologies that was my fault, i had written gridview not datagrid, am so used to using gridviews. i have edited the post, sorry

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you have images in your GridView that you want to display when a checkbox outside is selected. To do this, you will need to iterate through the rows of your GridView like so:

```
foreach (GridViewRow row in myGrid.Rows)
{
   Image myImage = row.FindControl("HiddenImage") as Image;

   //Hide or show image based on checkbox state
   myImage.Visible = checkShowImages.Checked;       
}
```

VB (a little rusty):

```
For Each row As GridViewRow In myGrid.Rows
    Dim myImage As Image = TryCast(row.FindControl("HiddenImage"), Image)

    'Hide or show image based on checkbox state
    myImage.Visible = checkShowImages.Checked
Next
```

Comment: I am using a datagrid not a grid view? Thanks

Comment: Your post title says that you were using a GridView. :-)

Comment: I know, i have just realised i wrote the wrong one, i am using a datagrid, apologies for this